# Convert an RDD into a key value pair RDD, with the values being in a List

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, keyvaluepair

I have an pairRDD with tuples being in the following form:

```
[(1,"b1","c1","d1","e1"), (2,"b2","c2","d2","e2"), ...
```

What I want is to transform the above into a key-value pair RDD, where the first field will be the key, and the second field a list of strings (value). i.e. I want to turn it to the form:

```
[(1,["b1","c1","d1","e1"]), (2,["b2","c2","d2","e2"]), ...
```

After this, is it then possible to access any field that I want?

For example, can I access the tuple `(1,["b1","c1","d1","e1"])`, then extract only the field `d1`?

Comment: This looks like a `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>` or `LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<String>>` if you want to preserver the keys' order.

Comment: should i use rdd.hashMap?

Comment: Oh, I've misunderstood, I thought you wanted to convert a RDD object to a normal Java object, as a RDD object, you can use `JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<String>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an RDD with Tuples, however the Tuples are represented, you can use [`mapToPair`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#mapToPair(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction)) to transform your RDD of Tuple into a PairRDD with Key and Value as preferred.

In Java 8 this could be

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,List<String>> r = 
  rddOfTuples.mapToPair((t)->new Tuple2(
      extractKey(t),
      extractTuples(t)
  ));
```

Note that this operation will introduce a shuffle.

To state the obvious, `extractKey` and `extractTuples` are to be methods to be implemented extracting the parts of the original tuple as needed.

With my limited knowledge of Scala Tuples, And assuming the input is something like `scala.Tuple5<String,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer>`, this could be:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,List<String>> r = 
  rddOfTuples.mapToPair((t)->new Tuple2(
      t._1,
      Arrays.asList(t._2,t._3,t._4,t._6)
  ));
```

If however, you do not know beforehand the arity (number of elements) of your `Tuple`, then in scala terms, it is a `Product`. To access your elements dynamically, you will need to use the `Product` interface, with a choice of:

- `int productArity()`
- `Object productElement(int n)`
- `Iterator<Object> productIterator()`

Then it becomes a regular Java exercise:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,List<String>> r = 
  rddOfTuples.mapToPair((t)->{
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(t.productArity()-1);
    for (int i = 1; i < t.productArity(); i++) {
      l.set(i-1,t.productElement(i));
    }
    return new Tuple2<>(t._1,l);
  }));
```

I hope I have it all right ... this code above is untested/uncompiled ... So if you can get it to work with corrections, then feel free to apply the corrections in this answer ...

Comment: but the problem here is that i want the value as a list

Comment: means the tuple ll be defined as (1,["hh","gg","hh"]) and 1 here represents the key

Comment: wold you modify your code please to show me how to do it?

Comment: no this is just an example it can be any type bcz i use diffrent data somtimes it s scala.Tuple5 or scala.Tuple3 or... so i need a standard function

Comment: What we really need is a better consolidation between core java and scala features ... I wish that Java inherits some of the best of scala (native tuple and list support) and Python (slicing) with none of the complexity, but consistent with java syntax.

Comment: wait a min .. your input tuple is actually a String? So you start with a RDD<String> ?

Comment: no it was a fault, i start with a JavaPairRDD<Integer, String>

Comment: but i can start with a RDD<string>? is it easier?

Comment: Much easier, handling the tuple is really cumbersome.

Comment: please, would you tell me how to  do it , and i m sorry

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a map function, eg in Scala:

```
rdd.map { case (k,v1,v2,v3,v4) => (k,(v1,v2,v3,v4)) }
```

Or rdd.groupBy could also be used but this could be inefficient on large data sets.

Comment: how can i do it in java

Comment: I'm not as familiar with using Spark in Java but this code might help: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=oryx-master/app/oryx-app-mllib/src/main/java/com/cloudera/oryx/app/batch/mllib/als/Evaluation.java - you can create a Function that takes Tuple5<Integer, String, String, String, String> as input and returns a Tuple2<Integer, List<String>>

Comment: Note that mapping it that way, still keeps it a as a non-keyed RDD, it will just be a new RDD of tuples.

Comment: but what if v1 .. v7? that's the more important issue